# PayPal "The Operation has timed out" wtih specific Credit Card

Tags: paypal

When attempting to pay with a specific test credit card it works fine 
but with any other card I get this error
Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Invalid HTTP response The operation has timed out

This happens consistently with any other test card number I try

I tested more than one account with the good card and it works but not with the others.

Here are the cards I am using

GOOD (Note: This came from PayPal Site)

Name: Betsy Buyer

Card No: xxxxxxxxxxxx0331 (417119669820331)

Card Type: visa

Name: Betsy Buyer

Expires: 11/2018

Valid Until: 9/16/2017

State: ok

BAD(I only got the number from a reference everything else is made up)

Name: John Lennon

Card No: xxxxxxxxxxxx1111(4111111111111111)

Card Type: visa

Name: John Lennon

Expires: 8/2019

Valid Until: 9/16/2017

State: ok

Comment: Generally the credit card number "4111111111111111" works good when PayPal is not your Processor . If PayPal is your processor I will advise not you this one as it gives the timeout error most of the time . You can use the below test cards 4446283288032978 , 4446283288034636 ,4446283288031707 ,4446283288033059 . You can put any CVV and any future date as expiration date .

Comment: Thanks Eshan. I will give them a try